# Covalent bonding in cuprates

Tags: superconductivity, chemical-compounds

In high temperature cuprate superconductors like YBCO, there are intermediate copper-oxide planes, where $Cu$ and $O$ atoms are arranged alternatively in a square lattice. In this arrangement, the $Cu$ atoms generally make 4 in-plane and 2 axial bonds, and each $O$ makes 2 in-plane bonds (see attached image).

[image: Copper-oxide planes in high Tc superconductors]

Oxygen's electron configuration $[He]2s^2 2p^4$, and can indeed form two bonds. However, copper has the electronic configuration $[Ar] 3d^{10} 4s^1$ which in the crystal field of the lattice becomes $[Ar] 4s^2 3d^9$, with the $3d_{x^2-y^2}$ orbital half-filled.

*What hybridisation does the $Cu$ orbitals undergo to be able to form four in-plane bonds. To form 6 bonds, it seems that the five 3d and one 4s orbitals will hybridise, but the $3d_{x^2-y^2}$ orbital is well separated from the other 3d orbitals in energy.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a good question  but one that belongs in Chemistry SE.

Comment: @Gert Typical comment here on questions about solid-state physics. There is a very unwelcoming attitude here.

Comment: Agree that this is solid state physics. Not quite sure how crystal electonic structure gets lumped with chemistry...

Comment: @Pieter: this is a very specific application of quantum chemistry, something that is the specialty of some types of chemist. Nothing unwelcoming here, simply a desire to have questions answered adequately. Note that the question has only received one vote so far. If no one else 'follows suit' then the question stays, no problem.

Comment: @Gert People like Edward Teller and John Van Vleck are counted as physicists, I think.

Comment: @Gert - wait, crystal bonding is now ‘quantum chemistry’? If it were just fcc copper would that still be true? Why didn’t Ashcroft and Mermin ever get told this isn’t Solid State Physics?

Comment: @JonCuster: Hold your fire: white flag hoisted! ;-)

Comment: @Gert - fire held! I just see too many good materials/semiconductor physics questions downvoted or closed around here (well, and lots of bad ones too - they can go away). Molecules? I'm fine with them on Chemistry. Crystalline solids? They should be here on Physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square-planar coordination is typical for a Cu(II) ion. Also when there are six ligands which could form an octahedral crystal field, the Jahn-Teller effect on a $3d^9$ configuration generally leads to the hole occupying the $3d_{x^2-y^2}$ orbital, and the bonds in the $z$-direction becoming longer.